# Getting started with Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

How do I get started as an Android developer? I know that I need to pay a fee, but I'm unsure about other things. I have done iOS development, so forgive me for making comparisons or assumptions based on the Apple App Store.

- How do I distribute my apps?
- Is there an app review process?
- What do I gain by paying Google the $25.00 fee?
- Does Google provide a dashboard where I can see statistics of my App downloads?
- What percentage does Google take from my App sales?
- What payment method does Android market use?
- When does Google do pay-outs, or do I get paid immediately?
- Is there a minimum pay-out threshold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How do I distribute my apps?

  Just upload them to the Android Market. There's only one initial fee of $25 USD.
- What percentage does Google take from my App sales?

> > For applications that you choose to sell in Android Market, the transaction fee is equivalent to 30% of the application price. For example, if you sell your application at a price of $10.00, the fee will be $3.00, and you will receive $7.00 in payment. [*Taken from this link*](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112622).

Basically all you need is in the FAQ... [this part](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324) is very important:

> ## Supported locations for merchants
>
> Currently, developers in the below
>   countries may register as Google
>   Checkout merchants and sell priced
>   applications:
>
> ```
> * Austria
> * France
> * Germany
> * Italy
> * Japan
> * Netherlands
> * Spain
> * United Kingdom
> * United States
> ```

Here you will find tons of information: http://market.android.com/support/?hl=en

Comment: Is the fee yearly or only once?

Comment: Only once... really cheap, isn't it? Actually Google charges that fee to avoid spam applications only... their business works differently from the Apple one.

Comment: To get started you only need a Google Account and a credit card.

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware of [Setting the Market Price](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138412) if you are coming from Apple. Once free forever free so be aware that you can't raise your app price after trying to do a limited time 'free' sale type of deal. Which explains the common practice of free/ad based version and a paid version of an app.